# Do MS Office applications notify Sharepoint/IE about modified files?

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, notifications, ms-office

In Sharepoint 2010, and only with Internet Explorer (version 9, but I expect it to be the same with newer versions), I noticed this behaviour.

**a**. Edit a document (either checking it out or not) in its own application, e.g. in MS Excel (see pic) - but it also works with Acrobat and PDF files;

[image: Sharepoint list file menu]

**b**. Make some edits and save the file;

**c**. Close Excel window.

At this point, I'd expect no action from IE. Instead, the document list refreshes, and shows  the modification date/time and author accordingly.

Does someone know how Sharepoint and IE accomplish this behaviour, that is **refresh when a file is saved and the editing program exits**?

**Please note**:

- the same refresh is done when there are several documents opened, and I close only the one I'm editing;
- this is only IE-related, since Sharepoint does not allow opening files in MS Office using e.g. Google Chrome.

Comment: It is probably implemented using javascript (program closed by ms word it self but refresh is done using javascript). Could you please tell what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets The same notification mechanism: launch an external editing application, and be notified when the user saves changes.

Comment: Maybe you can use sharepoint popup functionality?http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-pop-up-dialogs/

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets I don't see how. Anyway if you have a more detailed answer, please post it as an answer :)